# Java setting classpath in bash

Tags: java, bash

I've been having some trouble setting -classpath properly to get a project to run:

What I thought I was supposed to do:

```
java -classpath /path/to/classes package.Main
```

The only thing so far that works:

```
cd /path/to/classes
java -classpath . package.Main
```

I've also tried to do `-classpath /path/to/classes:.`

I need to be able to run that class from different directories so I can't use the solution that did work for me.

I am obviously missing something really stupid here.

EDIT: I am using cygwin

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the way classpath is handled in cygwin:

Since java is a windows program it doesn't recognize the cygwin path I gave.

The fix was:

```
java -classpath `cygpath -wp /path/to/classes/` package.Main
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: You dint mention you were using `cygwin` anyways good you could solve the issue.

Comment: I think I've done this before using paths starting with `/cygdrive/c` then specifying a Windows directory path.  Just a potential different approach.